# How to randomly sample data with seeding?

Tags: matlab, random, random-seed

I would like to randomly choose elements from a finite set that contains both numbers and `NaN`s while seeding the random number generation procedure.

So far I can make it work without seeding:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, nan];
sample = datasample(data, 50);
```

but if I want to seed the number generation:

```
seed = rng(100);
sample = datasample(seed, data, 50);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using datasample (line 89)
Sample size K must be a non-negative integer.
```

even if the syntax for `datasample` is (*):

```
[y,...] = datasample(s,data,k,...)
```

I have tried using `randsample`, too, but I get similar results.

(*) https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation isn't super explicit about the first input. You need to pass a [`RandStream`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html) object as the first input argument rather than the `struct` that `rng` generates (As a sidenote, the output of `rng` is the *previous* setting not the *new* settings).

Here is the equivalent of what it seems you were trying to do

```
stream = RandStream('mt19937ar', 'Seed', 100);
output = datasample(stream, data, k);
```

If you want to instead use `rng` to specify the seed, you can call `rng` and then use [`RandStream.getGlobalStream`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.getglobalstream.html) to get the current global random number stream and then pass *that* to `datasample`. This is slightly redudant though since `datasample` is going to use the global random number stream if one isn't provided.

```
rng(100)
stream = RandStream.getGlobalStream();
output = datasample(stream, data, k);
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the documentation to me. `rng` does not return a `RandStream` object. `datasample` calls `randi` under the hood, which only accepts a `RandStream` object as well (though this is not indicated in the documentation).

Comment: @horchler Yea the other functions (like `randsample`) mention this explicitly so maybe it is a bug of sorts.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. On a side note, my ultimate purpose was to generate an array containing numbers and `NaN`s chosen at random. Would you find my procedure acceptable to that end?

Comment: @PierPaolo As long as you want it to be equally likely that you get any number of a `NaN` then it should work, you could also use `randi` and keep an extra integer which you convert to a NaN after: `r = randi([0 6], 50, 1); r(r == 6) = NaN`. This wouldn't require any toolboxes

Comment: I've submitted a service request to The MathWorks to report this issue.